# c++ beep() как сделать когда я зажимаю кнопку звук удлинялся

Tags: c++

```
int asd;
asd = clock();

Beep(123, asd);
int qwe = 49;



while (true) {
    if (_kbhit()) {
        if (_getch() == qwe) {

            int *ptprees = &asd;
            Beep(123, *ptprees);
        }


    }
}
```

думал сделать так но

Comment: Ох уж эти ничего не значащие имена переменных и "магические" числа в коде...

Comment: вся логика в классе, я в main для проверки пишу так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int timeSound;

int enter = 49;

while (true) {
    timeSound = clock();// начинаем отсчёт для длительности звука
    if (_kbhit()) {
        if (_getch() == enter) {


            Beep(1256, timeSound); // передаём в beep для длительного воспроизведения
            Sleep(timeSound); // слип чтобы звук не прервался 
        }


    }
}
```

сделал может кому понадобится или сделает на основе этого лучше

Comment: Какой ужас. Ваш ответ не даёт НИКАКОЙ информации. Что такое `1256`? Что такое `qwe=49`? Что вам мешает напрямую передать переменную `asd` в `Beep` и `Sleep`? Без получения адреса, указателя и дальнейшего разыменования.

Comment: Поправил код, как только пройдет модерацию - станет получше.

Comment: У вас половина кода в ответе продублировалась...

Comment: переписывал через телефон не заметил

Comment: Ну опять же, 1256 - магическое число. вложенные if-ы не понятно зачем, два переноса строк, брр.

Comment: Поясните еще что за "// слип чтобы звук не прервался ", как это работает без слипа?